# Cache memory organization

Tags: c, caching, cpu-architecture

i would like to understand how the following program works in terms of main memory updating.

```
int main() { 
    short a[256], b[256]; 
    register i; 

    for (i=0 ; i < 256 ; i++) 
       a[i] = i; 
    for (i=0 ; i < 256 ; i++) 
       b[i] = 255 - i; 
    for (i=0 ; i < 256 ; i++) 
       b[i] = b[i] - a[i]; 
    return 0; 
}
```

I have an address bus of 16bits,main memory organized in bytes,cache memory size of 512 2-way set associative  ,block size of 16bytes and the CPU can only read information from the cache memory.

what happens when we use Write Through no write allocate policy
and what when we use Write back write allocate policy?

Comment: Your CPU has 8 kilobytes of cache, your code uses 1 KB of contiguous stack space, this memory spans 64 or 65 different lines of cache, everything fits well within the cache.  Yet the actual cache behaviour depends on how program code is read via the cache, potentially but unlikely causing contention and how data is read into the cache upon a cache write.  The third loop should not incur a cache miss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by

> cache memory size of 512

you mean `512 byte`.

And let's assume cache is empty and has nothing in it that is mapped to `a[]` or `b[]` region.

If your code runs with write back, then the first loop will be fully cache-missed. The third loop will fetch 16 byte after `a[i]` and `b[i]` when a miss happens, and continue to hit until the next block is reached (1 miss in 8 iterations).

With write-allocate, first two will have a miss every 8 iterations, and third loop is all-hit.

In this case, `a[]` and `b[]` are in the same set, so it's fine for the "2-way associative" part.
But if you declare more than 4 arrays of size `short[256]`, you'll have conflict.

```
int main() { 
    short a[256], b[256], c[256], d[256], e[256]; 
    register i; 

    for (i=0 ; i < 256 ; i++) 
       a[i] = i;// a in set0 
    for (i=0 ; i < 256 ; i++) 
       c[i] = 255 - i; //c in set 1
    for (i=0 ; i < 256 ; i++) 
       e[i] = c[i] - a[i]; // e/c/a evacuates each other
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I ran the program through MIPSIt simulator and i got more confused...
What if the a[i],b[i] data type is 1byte and every successful access of cache is 3cycles ,while the access time of main memory is 30cycles and every block  transfer between cache and main memory is 10cycles?
Also the program puts the element of a[i] to the  addresses that start from $2000 and the b[i] to $3000. 
how can one calculate the time that the program needs to update the memory in each case?
the program shows 26.800cycles for Write through no write allocate and 6.400cycles for write back write allocate.is it correct?